# Why do Diffraction lines in image not match the Spacing on the fringe pattern

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, optics, waves

In the attached image interference lines spreading out from the slits end up hitting the detection screen with unequal spacing. The spacing gets wider and wider the farther out it goes. On the other hand we know and can see that the actual fridge pattern spacing is equal.
[image]

Comment: the image on the far right shows both double slit and single slit interference patterns.

Comment: @JerrySchirmer Yes I realize that but the double slit spacing is equal and all the singles slit spacings are equal. The illustration showing Diffraction lines are not equal spacing.

Comment: Show a double slit diffraction pattern.

Comment: @ProfRob the image in red is a double slit pattern and  a single slit pattern.

Comment: Have you done the  trigonometry to get the spacing for a flat screen? Do you know that the detection screen was flat in the image you show? It doesn't correspond to what is shown in (a) and (b) where only a couple of maxima are seen and the angles are large.

Comment: Distance to the screen about 3.....4m?

Answer (score 1):

When you perform an optics double slit experiment the angular spread of the fringes is relatively small and so the fringes appear equally spaced which is what is predicted in the regime when the approximation $\sin \theta \approx \theta$ is reasonable.
To observe fringes for large angle is difficult because the fringes are not very bright although with a careful setup one can begin to see that the spacing charges for larger angles.

To observe the effect of having large angles easily then all one needs to do is use a diffraction grating which produces a set of principal maxima which mirror those of a double slit but are narrower and more intense.  With a grating the $\sin \theta$ dependence, ie unequal fringe spacing, is obvious.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this is not quite what I was asking. I’m talking about the distance between the bright spots. The bright fridges are equally spaced but if you look at the lines In figure a they spread out further and further.

Comment: The bright spots are the fringes that I was writing about.One difficulty is that they are broad and so accurate separation measurement are difficult.  If you could observe those bright spots at large angle you would find that the spacing was not constant.  However a diffraction grating allows you to do this.